# AngularJS directives don't seem to work with Python Flask

Tags: python, directive

Even though my issue might be a common one, I couldn't find a clear answer for it.
I'm a beginner with AngularJS and there is a very simple code that is not working, and actually all my directives doesn't work.
Here is my small project

```
/templates
    -index.html
    -header.html
    -script.js
mainapp.py
```

In index.html there is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in header.html

```
<div> I'm supposed to see this </div>
```

And mainapp.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def mainpage():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Nothing in script.js

When I'm running mainapp.py I'm expecting to see "I'm supposed to see this" but I don't because the directives doesn't seem to be working. However if I'm trying the html code alone (on Plunker for example) it's working fine.

I assume there is configuration that I need to do but I have no idea what, any ideas? (and if someone could provide an explanation for why it's not working that would be great)

Note that using data- before my directives doesn't change the issue.

Thanks

Comment: i wanted to help but its long to answer your query just giving u a tip know how to connect your angular app to your flask api route

Comment: I can surely investigate with your tip, thanks for it. I'll post the answer if i can find it, or post my desparation if not... We'll see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with how Flask handles static files vs. templates. The *header.html* file is really a static file in your situation, not a Flask template.

Change your directory structure to:

```
├── mainapp.py
├── static
│   └── partials
│       └── header.html
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Then update the `ng-include` to:

```
<div data-ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
```

If this were me, I wouldn't even use a "templates" directory. Just serve up a your *index.html* file from the static directory so that when an end user hits the main `/` route, Angular takes over. Then, you can just interact with the server-side via making AJAX requests against the RESTful API.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it's working indeed if I write <div data-ng-include="'static/partial/header.html'"></div>. There is still a particular behavior that I don't understand though, when I'm lauching the python it's working fine, however it's not if I'm lauching the html by double clicking, not that it matter much but I'm a little curious why

Comment: What do you mean by double clicking? You mean by going to the actual file and then double clicking so that it opens in your default browser?